# how to read and append values to an array in korn shell using += doesnt helping me

Tags: arrays, shell, sh

when i typed ps -p $$ i got

```
PID TTY       TIME COMMAND 
2788 pts/19    0:00 ksh
```

---

```
 #!/bin/ksh
    echo "enter timezones"
    read -a arr3 //how to append the values to this array dynamically
                  #as i want to give values like x1 x2 x3 x4 .....    "
    set -A arr4
    set -A tzarr1 nst3 ast4ad ast4 est5ed cst6cd mst7md cst6 mst7 pst8pd    
    set -A tztim1 12.0 12.5 13.5 13.5 14.5 15.5 15.5 16.5 16.5 
    p=0
    for i in "${arr3[@]}"
    do
    for j in "${tzarr1[@]}"
    do
    if [ "$i" = "$j" ];then
    arr4+=(${tztim1[p]})) //(shows error `('unexpected) how to append values
    break
    fi
    p=$(($p+1))
    done
    done
```

what my code do is it asks user for `timezones` as input and i give inputs as `ast4` `cast6cd` ... like this which are in "`tzarr1`" and the given inputs are to be stored in `arr3` array ,now the for loop searches for the value in `tzarr1` with the value in `arr3` ,when it got a match it breaks as it dont need to match with remaining elements. Now as i incremented p variable it holds the index value of the matched key in `tzarr1` so that using that index value i can store the value from `tztim1` to `arr4`.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Create a new array consisting of the contents of `arr4` and the item you want to add.</strike>

```
arr4=( "${arr4[@]}" "${tztim1[p]}" )
```

You have an extra parenthesis; remove it.

```
arr4+=(${tztim1[p]}))
      ^            ^^
      |            ||
      +------------+|
         matched    |
                    unmatched
```

Comment: it says syntax error '(' unexpected.
I want to know how to append values to an array in kornshell
arr4+=(${tztim1[p]})  ( want to append (${tztim1[p]}) to arr4 that i declared above so that whenever the equals to matches the value should append to the arr4)

Comment: Hm. I just checked, and `arr4+=(...)` should work. Are you sure you are actually executing your script with `ksh`? You aren't if you doing something like `sh myscript`, in which case `sh` (which does not support arrays at all) is used to execute your script, ignoring the shebang.

Comment: when i typed ps -p $$ i got

PID TTY       TIME COMMAND 
2788 pts/19    0:00 ksh.    This means I am using korn shell right?

Comment: That doesn't mean your are running your shell with `ksh`. What command do you type to run the script?

Comment: oh i run the script with scriptname.ksh (automate.ksh).i use chmod u+x automate.ksh to make it executable and run the script .How to know which shell i am using?
i am pretty new to shell script